# ¿Como puedo crear un excel desde R sin limite?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataframe, rstudio, data

He estado haciendo un data Frame de 65 columnas y 41542 filas, y a la hora de hacer el guardado y exportarlo desde R como un excel me salta este error.

```
  Error in .jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell",  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Cabe aclarar que estoy usando el paquete openxlsx de R.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). El problema que tienes es porque estás usando la biblioteca de funciona incorrecta para este trabajo (no está optimizada para generar el diccionario de términos fuera de la memoria). ¿Podrías indicar cuál es para sugerirte otra alternativa mejor? En particular, deberías mirar [writexl](https://docs.ropensci.org/writexl/) y [este documento (mira "Inline strings")](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/working_with_memory.html).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Muchas gracias! lo que pasa es que tuve que usar 60 excel diferentes porque en cada uno había una columna de interés con valores, para ellos, generé un objeto por cada uno, ejemplo: ```db0 <– read_excel("ruta excel", D1:D41453, col.type= c("numeric))```esto lo hice 60 veces, luego los acople todos en un nuevo objeto ```dataset <– data.frame(cbind(db0,...,db60))```. y ya con todos reunidos en un objeto hecho data Frame use la función ```write.xlsx()```
 del paquete mencionado antes.

Comment: Hay varios problemas, uno es que esa biblioteca de funciones almacena en memoria un diccionario de valores en el que se le asigna un índice a cada cadena de caracteres usada en cada celda, para usar ese índice en el contenido XML en vez del contenido en sí. Además, muchas veces el XML generado también se mantiene en memoria. Todo junto hace que se consuma demasiada memoria y la aplicación termine por fallar por ese motivo. Almacenar las cadenas en línea es una mejora en el rendimiento y uso de memoria y, sobre todo, generar el XML de manera secuencial en archivo en vez de en memoria.

Comment: Hacer ahora la elección correcta de la biblioteca de funciones te permitirá escalar en el futuro. No estoy seguro que la biblioteca que has elegido sea capaz de escalar correctamente haciendo uso de las optimizaciones que te he indicado.

Comment: Revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21937674/6836377 sino la otra posibilidad es que uses `openxlsx`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias amigo! usando rJava de ese link pude darle más memoria y lo logré. Igualmente a OscarGarcía por tu apoyo.